# table <td> tags not having a uniform and even size

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio, razor

I have a html table I am trying to build as formatting for a website banner and menu links. The menu links  tags however won't stay at an even size no matter how much size and margin fiddling I do.

```html
<table id="format_table">
    <tr>
        <th colspan=100>
            LOGO
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>Home</td>
        <td>Etc</td>
        <td>Etc</td>
        <td>Etc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @RenderBody()
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```css
table
{
    background-color: White;
    border: 1;
    border-width: 1;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 85%;
}

th
{
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}

td
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0 5 0 5px
}
```

Comment: Better provide the output of `@RenderBody()`.

Comment: Just FYI, `padding: 0 5 0 5px` is going to kick that property since `5` is not a valid value. Same issue with your `border: 1` and `border-width: 1`.

Comment: ah ok, these are just fragments of me trying results i find in google. and at the moment there is no output from RenderBody()

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
td { width:100px; height:50px; }
```